# Is there a way to name the same case but when is 2 times clicked?

Tags: javascript

I'm translating some interactives for a math school from English to Spanish. I'm having problems adapting the code to numbers in Spanish.

So I'm doing `case`s to change the order and the text (the numbers in Spanish have a different form to write between 20 and 24) in the console log the `case "veinte"` works to 20 but when you go 22 the `case "veinte"` count like 2 times "veinte" case. (see the image below)

[image: consolelog]

I don't know how to make a x2 of the same case. Sorry if I don't know how to make a good explanation of my problem, it's kind of confusing.

```
for(i = 0 ; i < q.length ; i++)
{


    if(q[i] != null)        
    {
        if(LowerCase)
            q[i] = q[i].toLowerCase();

        switch((3 - q.length) + i)
        {                   
            case 0:

                switch(q[i]){
                    case 'Cinco':
                        q[i] = 'Quinientos';
                        break;
                    case 'Siete':    
                        q[i] = 'Setecientos';
                        break;
                    case 'Nueve':    
                        q[i] = 'Novecientos' 
                        break;
                    case 'Uno':    
                        q[i] = 'Cien' 
                        break;
                    default:
                        q[i] = q[i] + "cientos";
                }
                vTemp = o.substring(i + 1);

                    if(parseInt(vTemp) > 0)
                        //q[i] = q[i] + " and";
                        q[i] = q[i] + "";

                break;

            case 1:
                 switch(q[i]){
                    case 'veinte':
                        q[i] = 'veinti';
                        break;


                    default:
                        q[i] = q[i];
                }
                if((q[2] != null) && (q[2] != "x"))
                    q[i] = q[i] + " y";
                break;

            case 2:
                if(q[i] == "x")
                    q[i] = "";
                break;



        }
        LowerCase = true;
    }
    else
    {
        q[i] = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a very high probability that somewhere on [NPM](http://npmjs.com) there's a library that already does this.

Comment: What's the input to this function, and the expected output? Seems like it would be easier to just find strings that end in "21", "22", "23", "24" and replace with the appropriate Spanish word.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?